# How to change window managers?

Tags: window-manager, openbsd

I have been trying to change my window manager from the default [cwm](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cwm_(window_manager)) to something different (probably [OpenBox](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openbox)).

Reading some articles online, it appears the configuration would be in the `$HOME/.xsession` file. However, this file does not exist.

```
ksh: /home/[user]/.xsession~: not found
```

Any help is highly appreciated, I am still very new to the BSD community. :)

Comment: It might be as simple as creating the file, and putting two lines such as `#!/bin/sh` and `cwm`

Answer (score 2):

Usually, there is a system-wide default Xsession script, which will normally first check if a user has their own `$HOME/.xsession` or similar, and will use it instead if it exists; otherwise the system-wide script will implement some system-wide default.

The location of a system-wide default script may depend on which X11 Display Manager (effectively the GUI login screen, e.g. `xenodm`) implementation you're currently using, or if you are using `startx` to start the GUI session after text-mode login.

- if you are using `startx`, the system-wide session script is either `/usr/X11R6/lib/sys.startxrc` or `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` in this order (first one that exists will be used). See: [`man startx`](https://man.openbsd.org/startx)
- if you are using `xenodm`, the system-wide default session script would be `/etc/X11/xenodm/Xsession`. See: [OpenBSD FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq11.html).
- if you are using some other display manager (usually named like `*dm`), you should check its documentation.

Note that `$HOME/.xsession` and `$HOME/.xsession~` are two different files, and the `~` suffix is a classic Unix text editor backup file indicator, i.e. `.xsession~` can be expected to be a previous/backup version of `.xsession` if it exists.